# Prolog, working my way through some examples

Tags: performance, recursion, prolog

I'm working through some Prolog tutorials (nothing better to do and I found out earlier this week I quite like programming, so I'm working through some paradigms) and got to an exercise asking me to write a predicate delete_from_list/3 which removes all given occurences from a list.

I've solved this as follows:

```
delete_from_list([], _, []).
delete_from_list([Ah|At], X, [Ah|Bt]) :- Ah \= X, !, delete_from_list(At, X, Bt).
delete_from_list([_|Ct], X, Bt) :- delete_from_list(Ct, X, Bt).
```

What I'm wondering though, and this might be more aesthetic than practical purpose. How would you guys do this in another way? And why?
This mostly to gain a broader understanding of ways of problem solving in prolog :)
For example, could this be done in 1 rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an if-then-else this can be done more elegantly (no cut involved):

```
delete_from_list([], _, []).
delete_from_list([X|Xs], Y, Result) :-
    (X = Y ->
        Result = Result0
    ;
        Result = [X|Result0]
    ),
    delete_from_list(Xs, Y, Result0).
```

And note that the predicate is still [tail-recursive](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Tail_call), meaning it doesn't allocate extra stack frames and uses a constant amount of memory apart from building up the `Result` list.

And yes, it can be done in one clause, but it's not pretty:

```
delete_from_list(Xs, Y, Result) :-
    (Xs = [] ->
        true
    ;
        Xs = [X|Xs0],
        delete_from_list(Xs0, Y, Result0),
        (X = Y ->
            Result = Result0
        ;
            Result = [X|Result0]
        )
    ).
```

Comment: Ah, nice, yeah. Now I've updated my member definition to:
    `is_on(Item, [H|T]) :- Item = H; is_on(Item, T)`
to be able to keep it in one clause :)
Now It's much easier to filter doubles out as well :) cheers

Comment: @ZedLep: that is a correct definition of `member/2` (apart from the name, of course). But believe me, defining disjunctive predicates with multiple clauses is usually better for readability and may also be faster, because Prolog compilers index on (build dispatch tables for) the first argument.

Comment: I see. I'm wondering, I'm trying to implement filter_doubles like so:
`filter_doubles([Ah|At], Result) :-
    (not(is_on(Ah, At)) ->
        Result = [Ah|Result]
    ;
        filter_doubles(At, Result)
    ).`
It makes perfect sense to me: if(H is not in T then put H in result, else recurse... Apparently prolog thinks otherwise. Am I thinking to imperative on this?
How could I define multiple clauses in my is_on then? Eiter item is equal to Ah or it isn't?

Comment: @ZedLep: please post this as a new question. It's quite hard to read code in comments.

Comment: Alright, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218041/prolog-if-and-stopping-recursion :-)

Comment: saying there's no cut in if-then-else in Prolog is like saying there's no monadic bind in do-notation in Haskell.

Comment: @WillNess: my point is that if-then-else is much easier to reason about than red cuts. This is Prolog without a cut like there is C without assembler; it's there, but you don't need to bother with it.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correctly understand this problem, select/3 do the same thing

```
?- select(3,[1,2,3,4],X), !.
X = [1, 2, 4].
```

Comment: Yeah, but since this is about learning I'm not using the built-in predicates ^^

Comment: Reading the source of the built-in predicates, however, could be instructional if they're done in Prolog.

Comment: The OP is not trying to implement `select`. Try it, and the OP's predicate, on `[1,1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is removeAllFromList/3 predicate using removeAllFromList/4 with [accumulator](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node51.html#subsec.l6.reverse.acc)

```
removeAllFromList(List, X, ListAns) :-
    removeAllFromList(List, X, [], ListAnsReverse),
    reverse(ListAnsReverse, ListAns),!.

removeAllFromList([], _, ListAns, ListAns).
removeAllFromList([H | Tail], X, OutList, ListAns) :-
    (
    (H =\= X, append([H], OutList, OutListNew))
    ;(H = X, OutListNew = OutList)
    ),
    removeAllFromList(Tail, X, OutListNew, ListAns).
```

Comment: The OP's version is already tail-recursive. Yours is just wasting time doing memory allocations in `reverse/2`.