# Prolog; if and (stopping) recursion

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, construction, if-statement

In trying to better understand prolog, lists and recursion as a whole I'm working my way through various simple tasks I've assigned to myself.
Among others is removing double entries from a list.

I've defined a rule:

```
is_on(Item, [Ah|At]) :- Ah = Item; is_on(Item, At).
```

This checks if 'Item' is on the list X or not. So I thought I could expand this to define a filter_double predicate as well:

```
filter_doubles([Ah|At], Result) :-
    (not(is_on(Ah, At)) ->
        Result = [Ah|Result]
    ;
        filter_doubles(At, Result)
    ).
```

This made perfect sense to me: if Ah doesn't occur in the rest of the list (its tail), then add a to the front of result using list construction, otherwise recurse over the rest of the list.
Apparently Prolog thinks otherwise:

```
47 ?- filter_doubles([1,2,3,3,4,2,1,1], Z).
Z = [3|**].
```

Am I thinking too imperative on this?

Comment: I suppose you mean `is_on(Item, [H|T]) :- Item = H; is_on(Item, T).` or `is_on(X,L) :- memberchk(X,L).`

Comment: Yeah, exactly, hurried making this post, not thinking about that one hehe

Comment: There's also a syntax error (missing paren), and is the predicate called `filter_double` or `filter_doubles`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need recursion in both branches, and you need a base case:

```
filter_doubles([], []).
filter_doubles([X|L], Result) :-
    (memberchk(X,L) ->
        filter_doubles(L, Result)
    ;
        filter_doubles(L, Result0),
        Result = [X|Result0]
    ).
```

`Result = [Ah|Result]` indeed seems to be a case of imperative thinking. What in means in Prolog is "unify `Result` with a term that has `Result` as its second argument," which either fails (in unification with occurs check) or produces a "rational tree" (an graph structure with a loop, in most Prologs).

Exercise: make the code I posted tail-recursive.

Note that this removes all but the last occurrence of each item.

Answer (score 3):

In logic programming, recursion in a predicate is often handled with more than one rule. The first rule describes the recursion base case, i.e. its halting condition; the other rules, or perhaps just the second one, describe the recursive step(s).

So, your `is_on` rule (which I have renamed `contains`) gets typically written in the following fashion:

```
contains(Item, [Item | _]).
contains(Item, [_ | Tail]) :- contains(Item, Tail).
```

The `filter_double` predicate may undergo a similar rewriting. First of all, an empty list will correspond to an empty result.

```
filter_doubles([], []).
```

Then, if the `Item` occurs in the `Rest` of the list, you recur over the `Rest` of the list, dropping that occurrence of `Item`.

```
filter_doubles([Item | Rest], Result) :-
    contains(Item, Rest), !,
    filter_doubles(Rest, Result).
```

Finally, if the `Item` does not occur in the `Rest` of the list (because the preceding rule has already checked out for that case), you are free to place that `Item` on the front of the result using list construction, and proceed to filter the `Rest` of the list.

```
filter_doubles([Item | Rest], [Item | Tail]) :- filter_doubles(Rest, Tail).
```

Please note that when you attempt to perform accumulation with an expression such as `Result = [Ah|Result]`, Prolog creates an infinitely recursive data structure: `Result` is unified with a list having `Ah` as head and `Result` as tail, which is unified with a list having `Ah` as head and `Result` as tail, which is unified with a list having `Ah` as head and `Result` as tail, and so on, and so on, and so on.

Comment: I hadn't even noticed the `Result = [Ah|Result]` yet. Expanded my answer with some comments on this. +1 to you.

Comment: Yeah, well, eventually I decided to try to explain that myself.